# Auto-hide panel in Qt or WxWidgets

Tags: qt, wxwidgets, hide, dock

I am looking to find a way to have a docked panel that would be similar to the panels within visual studio.

Essentially a panel that can be set to auto hide or can be pinned open.

Possibly this question was a bit vague. What I am looking for is essentially [this product](http://www.codejock.com/products/dockingpane/tour_43.asp)

Please leave a comment if I am missing details as I would like this question solved. I have searched google a fair bit and have not been able to find a possible solution. If worse comes to worse I will end up using a shortcut to hide and unhide the side panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt has [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html), maybe that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

check out the AUI demo in wxWidgets.

Comment: the wxAUI doesn't have that auto-hide/pinning feature the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Qt sadly doesn't support this. I've bugged them and others but got no word. I'm writing my own to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is a Visual Studio docking implementation for Qt.
It implements all the features that exist in a regular MFC docking - autohide panels, bars, floating windows and stickers.
If the task is still actual for you, you can try download the example here - http://www.devmachines.com/qtitandocking-overview.html